# Conditional Expectation of the minimum of two identical log-normal distributions

Tags: calculus, probability, logarithms, normal-distribution, expectation

I'd like to compute the closed form mean of the minimum of two truncated log-normal distribution (on another interval than its truncation).

I have: 
$\int_{a}^{\infty} \int_{a}^{\infty} min(v, v') \ f(v_{| v > b})f(v'_{| v' > b}) dv dv'$
Where $v' $ and $v \sim LogNormal(0, \sigma)$, and $f(v | v>b)$ represents the truncated log-normal density on $[b, +\infty]$.

I already computed the density $f$ (and its mean): I have:
$f(v|v>b) =  \frac{\frac{1}{v} \frac{1}{\sigma} \phi(log(v)/\sigma)}{1-\Phi(log(b)/\sigma)}$
where $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are the standard normal density and distribution functions.

The expectation of this process, on a truncated interval (from $c$ to $d$, where $c > b$) is given by:
$\mathbb{E}[v|b< c < v < d] = \int^d_c v \ f(v | v > b) = exp(\sigma^2/2) \frac{\Phi(\sigma - log(c)/\sigma) - \Phi(\sigma - log(d)/\sigma)}{1 - \Phi(log(b)/\sigma)}$

What I would like to obtain now is the expectation of the min of two draws from $f(v|v>b)$.
I rewrote the integral:
$\int_{a}^{\infty} \int_{a}^{\infty} min(v, v') \ f(v_{| v > b})f(v'_{| v' > b}) dv dv' = \int_a^\infty v_{min}f_{min}(v_{min} | v_{min} > b)$

(I m not sure this is correct but numerical trials seem to indicate that it was correct).

Since $Pr(v_{min} < x) = Pr(v < x) + Pr(v' < x) - Pr(v < x, v' < x) = 2 Pr(v < x) - Pr(v < x)^2$
(where the last equality comes from the fact that two identical truncated log-normal distributions are independent... I did not do the proof but I think it s correct)
I computed
$f_{min}(v | v > b) = 2 f(v | v > b) [1-F(v | v > b)]$

So now, I would like to compute the expectation of this, from a given $c> b$ to $\infty$, and I am stuck because I have:
$\begin{align*} \int^\infty_c v_{min} f_{min} (v_{min} |v_{min} > c) d v_{min}  &= \int^\infty_c v \ 2 f(v | v > b) [1-F(v | v > b)] dv \\
&= \underbrace{2 \int^\infty_c f(v | v > b) dv}_{\text{OK, expectation formula above}} - 2 \ \underbrace{\int^\infty_c v f(v | v>b) F(v|v>b) dv}_{\text{Problem here}} \end{align*}$

I need to compute the second term, which I know can be rewritten: 
$\begin{align*} 
\int^\infty_c v f(v | v>b) F(v|v>b) dv = \frac{1}{(1-\Phi(log(b)/\sigma))^2} \int_c^\infty v  \frac{1}{v} \frac{1}{\sigma} \phi(log(v)/\sigma) \Phi(log(v)/\sigma) dv - \underbrace{\frac{\Phi(log(b)/\sigma}{1-\Phi(log(b)/\sigma)} \int^\infty_c v f(v|v>b) dv}_{\text{OK, known using expectation formula}}
\end{align*}$

---

So basically (if all the rest is correct), I need to compute:
$\begin{align*}\int_c^\infty v  \frac{1}{v} \frac{1}{\sigma} \phi(log(v)/\sigma) \Phi(log(v)/\sigma) dv\end{align*}$

I'm not sure integrating by part work or anything... Does anyone has an idea?
Thanks in advance

---

Remark:
I also know that $\mathbb{E}[min(X_1, X_2)] = 2 exp(\sigma^2/2) \Phi(-\sigma/\sqrt{2})$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $LN(0, \sigma)$;
I need to extend this to the truncated log normal case.

---

My whole computation now comes down to this: 
I know that $\int^\infty_{-\infty} v f(v) F(v) dv = \Phi(\sigma/\sqrt{2}) exp(\sigma^2/2)$ 
I want to find : $\int^\infty_{c} v f(v) F(v) dv$. I think the result must not be too far from here, I just don't find it..

Comment: What has $[v|b<c<v<d]$ got to do with your stated question of finding "the expectation of the min of two draws from $f(v|v>b)$ ?

Comment: I was just giving the general formula of conditional expectation of the truncated process on other intervals (different from $>b$). (my end goal is to find the conditional expectation from $c$ (which is superior to $b$) to $\infty$).

Comment: Well, I suggest you start by dropping all the truncation ... and see if anyone can find a closed-form solution to the simplest problem:  finding the expectation of the minimum of 2 iid Lognormals. As it stands, your question appears too long and too complicated to do what it needs to do.

Comment: I already have this solution it's $= 2 exp(\sigma^2/2) \Phi(-\sigma/\sqrt{2})$ (for $LN(0, \sigma)$).  (it s written in the first post).  
My problem sums up to the last point in fact. How to integrate $v f(v) F(v) dv$ (to obtain the result). I think there is a simple trick to do so, I just don't know which one! 
If I know how to do it, I will be able to do it on a smaller interval (from $c$ to $\infty$) and solve my problem.

You re right maybe I should have made the question simpler, but I wanted to show all the details, etc.

Comment: The question is also asked and answered here:  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213753/expectation-of-two-identical-lognormal-distributions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial answer:

As said, before extending the work, lets work out the ordinary case first. Let $X_1 = e^{\sigma Z_1}, X_2 = e^{\sigma Z_2}$ where $Z_1, Z_2$ are i.i.d. standard normal. So

$$ \begin{align} &~ E[\min\{e^{\sigma Z_1}, e^{\sigma Z_2}\}] \\
=&~ E[e^{\sigma Z_1}\mathbf{1}_{Z_1 < Z_2}] + 
E[e^{\sigma Z_2}\mathbf{1}_{Z_2 < Z_1}]\\
=&~ 2E[e^{\sigma Z_1}\mathbf{1}_{Z_1 < Z_2}] \\
=&~ 2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}E[e^{\sigma Z_1}\mathbf{1}_{Z_1 < Z_2}|Z_1 = z] \phi(z)dz\\
=&~ 2\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\sigma z}\Phi(-z)\frac {1} {\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac {z^2} {2}\right\}dz\\ 
=&~ 2\exp\left\{\frac {\sigma^2} {2}\right\}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(-z)\frac {1} {\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left\{-\frac {z^2-2\sigma z + \sigma^2} {2}\right\}dz\\ 
=&~ 2\exp\left\{\frac {\sigma^2} {2}\right\}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(-z)\phi(z-\sigma)dz\\
=&~ 2\exp\left\{\frac {\sigma^2} {2}\right\}\Pr\{Z_1 + \sigma < Z_2\} \\
=&~ 2\exp\left\{\frac {\sigma^2} {2}\right\}\Pr\left\{\frac {Z_1 - Z_2} {\sqrt{2}} < -\frac {\sigma} {\sqrt{2}}\right\} \\
=&~ 2\exp\left\{\frac {\sigma^2} {2}\right\}\Phi\left(-\frac {\sigma} {\sqrt{2}}\right)\\
\end{align}$$

Here the key trick should be exploiting the normal pdf by completing the square and thus we have changed the measure. To extend it to truncated case, note that

$$ e^{\sigma z} > b \iff z > \frac {\ln b} {\sigma} \triangleq a$$

Now we try to modify the calculation accordingly:
$$ \begin{align} &~ E[\min\{e^{\sigma Z_1}, e^{\sigma Z_2}\}|Z_1 > a, Z_2 > a] \\
=&~ 2\int_a^{\infty}E[e^{\sigma Z_1}\mathbf{1}_{Z_1 < Z_2}|Z_1 = z, Z_2 > a] \frac {\phi(z)} {\Phi(-a)}dz\\
=&~ 2\exp\left\{\frac {\sigma^2} {2}\right\}\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac {\Phi(-z)\phi(z-\sigma)} {\Phi(-a)^2}dz\\
=&~ 2\exp\left\{\frac {\sigma^2} {2}\right\}\frac {1} {\Phi(-a)}\Pr\{Z_1 + \sigma < Z_2|Z_1 + \sigma > a\} \\
\end{align}$$

So in the last step it involve a bivariate normal CDF, which cannot be in terms of the univarate normal CDF as before.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. The reason why I need the formula is to avoid numerical integration in a dynamic program code (in order to avoid losing time). Is there a way to compute (quickly) this bivariate normal CDF, or am I stuck with numerical integration? (I want to avoid integration as much as possible)

Comment: In computer, every function (even the closed form function square root/exponential, and normal CDF of course) require numerical computation, so the only point is that how efficient the algorithm to compute the solution and the convergence issue etc. (Not good at these numerical computations issue)

Comment: Yep indeed, but asking the computer to use numerical integration algorithm is generally considerably longer than using function of pdf (at least it is with R). Anyway I think there might be a way to rewrite $\int_a^\infty \Phi(-z)\phi(z-\sigma) dz$ without the integral, I hope so and I'm looking into it right now

Comment: If you are using R, there are some packages like mvtnorm provide functions to compute the probabilities. You may try to see if that algorithm satisfy your need or not. Btw please check if my calculation is correct; if it is correct, then it is not possible to reduce a general bivariate normal probability into a "simpler" form like the formula you provided in the example.